# Hackerrank - why is my output being written one character at a time?

Tags: python-3.x, output

I am solving the following "Vertical Sticks "hackerrank challenge: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/vertical-sticks/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

Here is my solution:

```
def solve(y):

    out = []
    x = list(itertools.permutations(y))
    
    for yp in x: 
        
        arr = []
        arr.append(1)
        for i in range(int(1),int(len(yp))):
            #flag = 0
            for j in range(int(i-1),int(-1),int(-1)):
                if yp[j] >= yp[i]:
                    arr.append(i-j)
                    #flag+=1
                    break
                if j==0:
                    arr.append(i+1)
        out.append(sum(arr))
 
    
    p = round((sum(out)/len(out)),2)
    pp = "%0.2f" % (p)
    print(pp)
    return pp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    t = int(input().strip())

    for t_itr in range(t):
        y_count = int(input().strip())

        y = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

        result = solve(y)

        fptr.write('\n'.join(map(str, result)))
        fptr.write('\n')

    fptr.close()
```

My print(pp) output comes out correctly for the test case as:

```
4.33
3.00
4.00
6.00
5.80
11.15
```

But my return pp stdout comes out as:

```
4
.
3
3
3
.
0
0
4
.
0
0
6
.
0
0
5
.
8
0
1
1
.
1
5
```

i.e. one character per line, and is classified incorrect. Could somebody point me into the direction of why this is?

Answer (score 1):

The return from solve is already a string. When you call `join` on it, you are splitting it into its individual characters, separated by newlines.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately I cannot edit anything below "if __name__ == '__main__':"  and my attempt at returning p instead of pp fails to "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable". How do I return the solution to two decimal places in the function?

Comment: @tt123321 The HackerRank codes includes this comment at the top `# The function is expected to return a DOUBLE_ARRAY.
# The function accepts INTEGER_ARRAY y as parameter.`
The comment is a bit misleading because I think it is intended for a different language. However, what its saying is that your function should be returning a list of floats, rather than just one float or a string.